# Find gridview linkbutton value jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

my gridview got few column.Column 1 is **ID** which is a **linkbutton** field , column 2 is **CustName** which also is a **linkbutton** field, column 3 is address which is a normal cell text .Here i got a question. How can i get the column 2 value  when i click the ID button by Jquery?

Here my coding

```
   $("a.ID").click(function (e) {
            var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        var Desc= row.children("td:eq(2)").text();
            var test = row.children("td:eq(1) a").text();???Here error
            alert(test);

        });
```

I am able to get the colum 3 value when click the particular selected row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know outright why that doesn't work, but try separating it:

```
row.children("td:eq(1)").find('a').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample solution http://jsfiddle.net/3hsvQ/

```
$('.idColumn').click(function (event) {
    var cell = $(event.currentTarget),
        row = cell.parent().parent(),
        nameCell = row.children()[1];
    alert(nameCell.innerText);      
});
```

For this html:

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="idColumn">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nameColumn">Foo</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="idColumn">2</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nameColumn">Bar</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="idColumn">3</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nameColumn">FooBar</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add the code into the answer, so that it's actually an answer?

Answer (score 0):

First you can declare function in JavaScript section as below.

```
function GetValue(va)
{
  var CustName = $(va).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
}
```

After you can call function from `OnClientClick` property of button. So declared as given below.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDetails" runat="server" Text="<img src='../img/Details.png'>" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="GetValue(this);"></asp:LinkButton>
```